# How to check zip file in pl/sql

Tags: plsql

At work, I need to regularly send zip archives from files that are in the database. Sometimes the files in the archives break, which greatly disrupts the work. Is there a way to check the archive in PL/SQL?

Comment: I wouldn't know, but - "checking ZIP files" is **not** a database job (in my opinion). You should do that check elsewhere (at the operating system level).

Comment: Maybe there are packages that can check

Comment: I would use a java stored procedure, if it must be done inside the database engine.